# What happens to my already-published game when I upgrade to Unity Pro?

Tags: unity

I made a game with Unity's Standard liscense, and published it (version 1.0) on Google Play. If I buy a Unity Pro license can I publish an update to my game (version 2.0) with it on Google Play, or must I create a new game on Google Play for the updated version?

Comment: How have you tried updating your game so far? Where did you run into trouble?

Answer (score 3):

Building with Pro Unity as opposed to Standard will not change how you submit the application to Google. It will be the same app with the same ID. Make sure you keep your signing password.

Comment: Thanks so it can launch it with pro  within change

Comment: Yes, that is what he is saying. Changing the client won't in anyway change the build output. Once you have verified this information, please accept it.