# how update my game on google play(unity plus)?

Tags: unity, google-play-services, google-play

If I published  A game with unity plus license on google play (play store)so can  I update my game with unity Pro license Or I have to a  new create game o google play?

Comment: What's the difference with the question you [asked before](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/168862/what-happens-to-my-already-published-game-when-i-upgrade-to-unity-pro)?

Comment: It was for unity standard license and Go to pro but this is Plus to Pro

Comment: Why would that change the answer in any way? Have you tried applying the previous answer to this case and encountered any specific problem?